# Install Dlib in Anaconda Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, dlib

I'm trying to install the `dlib` package in Anaconda by running the following:

```
conda install -c menpo dlib
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
- dlib
- zict
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you install zict from conda-forge ?

Comment: Try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58570219/problem-in-installing-dlib-module-for-anaconda-on-mac-os/58624181#58624181

Answer (score 0):

You should go to the [Python Index Page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dlib/19.6.0) to download the specific whl for your python, then put it into site-packages folder.

cd into this folder and use the command `pip install XXX.whl`

Attention you should notice:

1 make sure boost,boost-python,opencv-python have already been installed.

2 use the command `print(pip.pep425tags.get_supported())` to learn which specific wheel your python support.

3 The dlib version should match your python version.

Comment: \ wan Is it .xml or .whl ?

Comment: I have changed the mistake, thanks for you comments.

Answer (score 0):

**Installers**
Info: **This package contains files in non-standard labels.**

- linux-64  v19.22.0
- win-32  v19.9
- osx-64  v19.22.0
- win-64  v19.22.0

To install this package with conda run one of the following:

```
conda install -c conda-forge dlib
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 dlib
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 dlib
```

Answer (score -1):

Use below command in your script for the first time.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(["python", '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'dlib']) # install pkg
```

Comment: why not just issue the shell  cmd

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work that way in my case, not sure why.

Comment: proba ly due to $PATH

Comment: Yes it was and I was having multiple environments so I found this line of code a better option.