# problem in installing dlib module for anaconda on mac os

Tags: python, cmake, anaconda, dlib

Im trying to install dlib on my mac os, I used anaconda and the picture below is an error occurred when i attempted to install the module.

I did install cmake, but it still failed.

Thank you in advance for helpiing me to figuring this out, cheers.

[image: it fails with following output]

Comment: Please do *not* post images or your error. Instead, copy/paste the error text into your **question post**; you will be much more likely to get help when you post the error text itself!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dlib is support with **python 3.6 to 3.7.0** versions. Try to install the dlib in anaconda prompt by following command.,

step 1:
conda create -n env_name python=3.7.0

step 2:
conda activate env_name

step 3:
conda install -c conda-forge dlib=19.17

-c is stands for channel, conda-forge is one of channels.

you can find all supported packages for conda's in this link https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/