# unable to install dlib for python windows 10 (cmake installed)

Tags: python-3.x, cmake, pip, windows-10, dlib

Trying to install dlib for python on Windows 10 by building it from source for quite a while now and have searched a lot to find a good solution. I tried to follow the following steps.

1. I first installed VS 16 2019 with all the required c++ dev tools([check attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypeKW.png)) and then installed cmake.
2. Then pip installed cmake.
3. Now when I write "pip install dlib". It collapses by showing the
   following output([check attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCOwO.png)):

```
  -- Building for: Visual Studio 14 2015

  -- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.19042.

  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (project):

    Failed to run MSBuild command:
      MSBuild.exe

    to get the value of VCTargetsPath:
      The system cannot find the file specified
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I think the problem here is that cmake is using "VS 14 2015" by default when I run "pip install dlib". Is there a way to change this default to use "vs 16 2019" in cmake.

Comment: Try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58570219/problem-in-installing-dlib-module-for-anaconda-on-mac-os/58624181#58624181

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just recently tried something that just worked. I installed all the versions of C++ build tools that were available in VS 2019. Then installed dlib with pip and it worked.